# Postgres array_to_string() with array in JSONB field

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I want to get a TEXT of an array in JSONB field. The string that I expected are the following :

```
dom1.com,  dom2.com,  dom3.com
```

The JSONB field contains that :

```
{
    "id": 10,
    "domain_list": [
        "dom1.com",
        "dom2.com",
        "dom3.com"
    ]
}
```

I try to use the array_to_string() function by using the following code :

```
SELECT
    array_to_string(
        jsonb_array_elements(
            '{"id": 10,"domain_list": [  "dom1.com",  "dom2.com",  "dom3.com"]}'::jsonb->'domain_list'
        ),
        ', '
    );
```

But it returns the error

```
ERROR:  function array_to_string(jsonb, text) does not exist
LINE 2:         array_to_string(
                ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I also try this

```
SELECT string_agg(domain_list::text, ', ')
FROM json_array_elements(
    '{"id": 10,"domain_list": [  "dom1.com",  "dom2.com",  "dom3.com"]}'::jsonb->>'domain_list'
) as domain_list;
```

But it returns the error

```
ERROR:  function json_array_elements(text) does not exist
LINE 2:     FROM json_array_elements(
                 ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `->` operator (return value as json) and proper function for you type, `jsonb_array_elements` in this case:

```
SELECT 
    string_agg(domain_list::text, ', ')
FROM jsonb_array_elements(
    '{"id": 10,"domain_list": [  "dom1.com",  "dom2.com",  "dom3.com"]}'::jsonb->'domain_list'
) as domain_list;
```

More info [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html).

Comment: Thank you. I forgotten to use **->** in this case

Comment: glad to help you @jedema